# How can I set up multiple dynamic users to update a single network's dynamic IP

Tags: laptop, home-networking, opendns, dynamic-ip, dynamic-dns

On my home network we are allocated a dynamic IP. I want to configure ddclient (or an equivalent) to send IP updates to DNS-O-Matic/OpenDNS **only** when I am on my home network. I do not want to send IP updates when I'm on my office network. Can this be done? I am prepared to use different FLOSS software or a different free DNS service.

Additionally, there are multiple users who may be on the home network or away on other networks. How can we configure ddclient on each machine so that whoever is on the home network updates the IP (i.e. so we don't have to rely on a particular machine being on the network to update the IP). OpenDNS support have said we can't simply install updater software on each machine.

Comment: Does your home router have support for updating this sort of service? Mine is quite a few years old, but supports sending updates to one or two specific services that are like DNS-O-Matic (I can't remember which is supports off the top of my head, doesn't really matter). This way, you don't reply on *any* machine being switched on and don't have to worry about sending false updates when you're away from your home network.

Comment: ah, it looks like it does, but not for OpenDNS/DNS-O-Matic - I'll investigate further - leaving the question as-is for non-router solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there isn't currently a tool to do this.